# In CSP, what's unsafe about 'unsafe-inline'?

Tags: browser, content-security-policy

Why is 'unsafe-inline' unsafe in a Content Security Policy?

What's wrong with inline scripts? is it just unsafe comparing to providing a hash or a nonce? or is there something I'm missing about embedding inline scripts instead of remote scripts?

Answer (score 3):

Inline scripts are unsafe because of XSS. When allowing 'unsafe-inline' you whitelist your own inline scripts as well as any maliciously embedded script. With hash or nonce you can whitelist your own scripts while blocking all other scripts from executing.